# Finding the length of the longest repeating 1s in a string

Tags: python

I was wondering how one can find the length of the longest repeating 1s in a string of 1s and 0s in python, taking into account the empty string. like`'1011110111111'` would return `6` and `''` would return `0`.

A past post suggested using regex,

`max([len(i) for i in re.compile('(1+1)').findall(count)])`

but it doesn't count the case for one single 1 and the empty string.

Comment: This is pretty simple to do with a loop and a counter. Please show what attempt you have made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just split the string using '0' as separator and find the longest item in the list:

```
s = '1011110111111'
result = len(max(s.split('0')))
```

Comment: In my Python 3.5.2 on Windows 10 from the Anaconda3 distribution, that does give `0` for the empty string. Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: Interesting. Without thinking it through, I thought `max(map(len, s.split('0')))` would be much faster for large strings, but whatever strings I tried, the difference was small because `s.split('0')` took most of the time anyway. Makes sense, though, I think both solutions are O(len(s)).